# Different Python versions on single PC

Tags: python, installation

I want to install different versions of Python (and related packages and IDEs) on a single PC and keep them independent. I like the pythonxy but runs on Python 2.6, but I also wat to try Eric5 with Python3.1. 
How can I keep thess different install separated ?

Comment: What operating system are you running? The detailed procedure depends on this.  Also: do you want to install from pre-built packages or are you building Python from source?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, this is trivial. You just install both, they get put in different directories.

On Linux, this is less so, but still fairly simple. Install from source, and use `make altinstall` instead of `make install`.

Comment: Ok, but I think I get dependecies between some packages that install with both the IDEs. I think I had noticed that one istall package ruined the other IDE. I use win 7. thnx